# Retrieving SCOPE_IDENTITY() with QSqlQuery

Tags: sql-server, database, qt

```
bool ok = query.exec("CREATE TABLE person ( IdTable INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, LastName varchar(255), FirstName varchar(255)  )");            
bool ok1 = query.exec("INSERT INTO person VALUES ('Wijethilake','Tharanga')");            
QSqlQuery scope_Identity("SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS Current_Identity;");
QSqlRecord rec = scope_Identity.record();
qDebug() << scope_Identity.isValid();
```

This returns false. IS it that something wrong with qt or is my scope Identity statement wrong. I really appreciate someone's help on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be related to how QSqlQuery operates.

I don't know QSqlQuery, but I have had a similar issue with `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` in other languages where the `INSERT` and `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()...` statements are run in different scopes - meaning that the results of the `INSERT` are not accessible to `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` - typically because they are executed as dynamic SQL by the data access layer. You can validate this by running a SQL trace on your database server for `SQL:BatchCompleted` events.

Assuming this is the issue, you need to execute both statements in the same scope to return the new identity. I'm not sure if this is valid QSqlQuery, but something like

```
QSqlQuery scope_Identity("INSERT INTO person VALUES ('Wijethilake','Tharanga'); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS Current_Identity;");
QSqlRecord rec = scope_Identity.record();
qDebug() << scope_Identity.isValid();
```

In SQL 2005 and later, an alternative to `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is the `OUTPUT` clause, which enables you to do the whole thing in one statement:

```
QSqlQuery scope_Identity("INSERT INTO person OUTPUT inserted.IdTable VALUES ('Wijethilake','Tharanga');");
QSqlRecord rec = scope_Identity.record();
qDebug() << scope_Identity.isValid();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply and I have to tell you that the second part of of your question helped me.

Answer (score 1):

This will not work if person has any trigger for insert:

```
QSqlQuery scope_Identity("INSERT INTO person OUTPUT inserted.IdTable
    VALUES ('Wijethilake','Tharanga');");
```

I'm not sure why this will not work:

```
QSqlQuery scope_Identity("INSERT INTO person VALUES
    ('Wijethilake','Tharanga');  SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS
    Current_Identity;");
```

You can do it like this:

```
QString query("**some_query_to_insert; some_query_to_select_with_SCOPE_IDENTITY()**");
QSqlQuery sql(QSqlDatabase::database());
sql.exec("**EXEC('**"+query+"**')**");
sql.next();
QVariant v = sql.value(*n*);
```